# Convergence in law and sequence of reals

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How to show that if I have $Y_n$ a sequence of random variables and $a_n$ a sequence of reals such that

(i) $Y_n\to Y$ in law

(ii) $a_n\to a$

i have $a_nY_n\to aY$ in law?

I know that if I have (i) $\Rightarrow$ $h(Y_n)\to h(Y)$ in law if $h$ is continuous. I can say $a_nY_n$ is continuous ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem#Proof